# YouTube Live Streaming API Snippet.scheduledStartTime not Working while Creating Live Broadcast

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-apis-explorer, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am creating `YouTube` live broadcast using API explorer everything is working fine but `Snippet.scheduledStartTime` is not working fine.

My time zone is +05:00 and country is Pakistan.

I want to schedule event at `2019-01-18 04:50 PM`. I have set the `Snippet.scheduledStartTime` to `2019-01-18T11:50:00.000Z` but on event page it shows `Starts January 18, 2019 at 3:50 AM (PST)` when I click edit it shows wrong country and time zone like that `United States (GMT -08:00) Pacific`

I want to use `javascript` or `php` client libraries.

Please let me know how I can fix it?

Here is my php code

```
$broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
$broadcastSnippet->setTitle('New Test Broadcast');
$broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime('2019-01-18T11:50:00.000Z');
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  We cant help you fix your php or JavaScript code without seeing it.     API explorer is used for testing only and may have bugs so we cant help with that.

Comment: Hello @DaImTo i have edit my question and added php code

Comment: Hello @DaImTo i am waiting for your reply

Comment: So that you understand how stack works.  You need add your code to your questions always. It will improve your chances of getting an answer.  I never said i had an answer i was just trying to help you as a new user get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [YouTube Live Streaming API Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts), the format for `scheduledStartTime` must be in ISO 8601 format:

> `datetime`
>
> The date and time that the broadcast is scheduled to start.
>   The value is specified in [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

I would suggest that you check the `time zone designator` you have set.

**Create date with timezone**

I am not a PHP dev but the smartest thing to do IMO would be to create a date in the correct timezone and then out put it in the correct format.  After about five minutes of googleing i found this.

```
$tz = 'Europe/London';
$timestamp = time();
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
echo $dt->format('c');
```

Comment: Hello @DalmTo i have tried this but still its not working same behariour

Comment: I would check the timezone of the user who is owns the channel

Comment: Where i can check the timezone of the user who is owns the channel by the way when i create new event from youtube live dashboard its shows me correct country and my timezone but in case of using API i have problem